show the rows with highest value in the group in mysql
SELECT 
        CorrelationId,
        EINNo AS EIN,
        ClientNo AS `Client-No`,
        PackageReference2 AS PackageRef2,
        COALESCE(UPSTracking, USPSTracking) AS TrackingNo,
        CartonID AS CartonId,
        ZipFileName AS `ZIPFILE name`,
        ProductionFacility AS Facility,
        MAX(ProductionStatusNo) AS Status,
        MAX(StatusDateTime) AS StatusDateUTC
    FROM 
        detail  
    GROUP BY 
        CartonId ; 

shows the rows with highest (ProductionStatusNo)  in group so that in case there is ProductionStatusNo reached 9 or 10 there always will be a value for (UPSTracking, USPSTracking) and if carton not reached at the ProductionStatusNo equals to 9 or 10 then there will be null values for UPSTracking or  USPSTracking .

Your query is invalid according to ANSI SQL.  Can you add some sample table data to your question which helps to explain it?

its working for 8.0 version.

Given that you seem to be using MySQL 8+, you can probably just use ROW_NUMBER() here:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CartonId
                                 ORDER BY ProductionStatusNo DESC) rn
    FROM detail
)

SELECT
    CorrelationId,
    EINNo AS EIN,
    ClientNo AS `Client-No`,
    PackageReference2 AS PackageRef2,
    COALESCE(UPSTracking, USPSTracking) AS TrackingNo,
    CartonID AS CartonId,
    ZipFileName AS `ZIPFILE name`,
    ProductionFacility AS Facility,
    ProductionStatusNo AS Status,
    StatusDateTime AS StatusDateUTC
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;

Note: An index on (CartonId, ProductionStatusNo) should improve performance of the above query, e.g.
CREATE INDEX idx ON detail (CartonId, ProductionStatusNo);


I have index or cartonId in detail , detail table is very large containing around 10M records

@rahularyansharma I have provided an index suggestion which should help with performance.
